# How to properly setup a "library-chain" in visual studio?

Tags: c++, configuration, static-libraries, linker-errors, visual-studio-2022

I am having problem setting up the library configuration for my executable project in visual studio 2022.
In my solution I have this three following projects:

- Common (lib)
- Render (lib)
- Game (executable)

The idea is that the Common library should be included in every library I'll add to my solution in the future and in the end, the Game project will include all other library projects in my solution.

So: Render.lib have is using Common.lib. Game.exe is using Render.lib and Common.lib.

Right now, the **Common** library and the **Render** library builds without any problem at all but the **Game** project will not build due to linking errors to the **Render** project.

### **Project Setup**

Each project have three directories: **External**, **Include** and **Source**.
Each project have their own pre-compiled-header.

**The External directory** contains an *include* and *lib* a directory. The *include* directory holds all include files for the library files in the *lib* directory.
**The Include directory** contains all include files for the current project.
**The Source directory** contains all source files for the current project.

### Building

- First, the **Common** library is built and its include files are copied to Render/External/Include/Common/ and Game/External/Include/Common. The Common lib-file is copied to Render/External/lib/Common.lib and Game/External/lib/Common.lib.
- Second, the **Render** library is build and its include files are copied to Game/External/Include/Render/. The Render lib-file is copied to Game/External/lib/Render.lib. (I have also tried to copy the **Render** project *External* directory to the **Game** project *External/lib/* directory).
- Third, the **Game** project is built and here I get link errors to the **Render** project.

### Game Property Pages:

[VC++ Directories]
External Include Directories: $(ProjectDir)External\include
Library Directories: $(ProjectDir)External\lib

[Linker->Input]
Additional Dependencies: Common.lib;Render.lib

---

- Have anyone done this Solution setup before?
- Any suggestions of what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

I have tried to fiddle around in the Game Property Pages to see if I can find any logical error in my configuration. I have also tried to remove the pre-compiled headers if they had something to do with my linking problem (I've also tried to copy them and not copy them).

The changes I've made have not yielded anything other then that the Include files are not found for the external projects...

EDIT:
Here is the link error:

```
1>RenderEngine_Debug.lib(Renderer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class Render::Renderer Render::Renderer::gRenderer" (?gRenderer@Renderer@Render@@0V12@A)
1>RenderEngine_Debug.lib(WindowEvent.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::vector<struct Render::Event::Message,class std::allocator<struct Render::Event::Message> > Render::Event::EventHandler::myEventQueue" (?myEventQueue@EventHandler@Event@Render@@0V?$vector@UMessage@Event@Render@@V?$allocator@UMessage@Event@Render@@@std@@@std@@A)
1>RenderEngine_Debug.lib(WindowEvent.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::unordered_map<enum Render::Event::Type,class std::unordered_map<class Render::Event::Subscriber *,bool,struct std::hash<class Render::Event::Subscriber *>,struct std::equal_to<class Render::Event::Subscriber *>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class Render::Event::Subscriber * const,bool> > >,struct std::hash<enum Render::Event::Type>,struct std::equal_to<enum Render::Event::Type>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<enum Render::Event::Type const ,class std::unordered_map<class Render::Event::Subscriber *,bool,struct std::hash<class Render::Event::Subscriber *>,struct std::equal_to<class Render::Event::Subscriber *>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class Render::Event::Subscriber * const,bool> > > > > > Render::Event::EventHandler::mySubscribers" (?mySubscribers@EventHandler@Event@Render@@0V?$unordered_map@W4Type@Event@Render@@V?$unordered_map@PEAVSubscriber@Event@Render@@_NU?$hash@PEAVSubscriber@Event@Render@@@std@@U?$equal_to@PEAVSubscriber@Event@Render@@@5@V?$allocator@U?$pair@QEAVSubscriber@Event@Render@@_N@std@@@5@@std@@U?$hash@W4Type@Event@Render@@@5@U?$equal_to@W4Type@Event@Render@@@5@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBW4Type@Event@Render@@V?$unordered_map@PEAVSubscriber@Event@Render@@_NU?$hash@PEAVSubscriber@Event@Render@@@std@@U?$equal_to@PEAVSubscriber@Event@Render@@@5@V?$allocator@U?$pair@QEAVSubscriber@Event@Render@@_N@std@@@5@@std@@@std@@@5@@std@@A)
1>RenderEngine_Debug.lib(WindowEvent.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static bool Render::Event::EventHandler::SkipEvents" (?SkipEvents@EventHandler@Event@Render@@0_NA)
1>D:\Projects\Steve\Steve\x64\Debug\GameEngine.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "GameEngine.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Comment: Doesn't VS have "project references" so you can simply link to generated artifacts?

Comment: @rainbow.gekota
Hi, I have now added the link errors to my post. Sorry for leaving it out. I thought the actual link error message was a little bit to specific to be of any help.

Comment: @Botje
Maybe, I have not used that kind of configuration before.

Comment: I'm glad you got your issue resolved. As for whether the way it got resolved can be helpful to other users, I'm not so sure, since the question post doesn't include the code that the link error is related to. This is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out...
It seems that my configuration was not faulty, I had just forgotten to define the static variables you can see in the link errors.

With this fixed everything is fine and working!

Thank you and sorry for taking your time regarding this...